# Getting "ORA-28759: failure to open file" while trying to connect to TLS1.2 enabled Oracle DB

Tags: go

I am trying to connect to *TLS1.2* enabled *Oracle DB*. I am using *godror package* (Go Driver for Oracle DB). While trying to connect, I am getting "**ORA-28759: failure to open file**". Please find the attached code snippet that is being used:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"
    "time"

    godror "github.com/godror/godror"
)


func main() {

    var P godror.ConnectionParams
    
    P.Username = <username>
    P.Password = godror.NewPassword("<password>")
    P.ConnectString = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=<hostname>)(PORT=<port>))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=<service_name>)))"

    db := sql.OpenDB(godror.NewConnector(P))

    dberr := db.Ping()
    
    if dberr != nil {
        log.Printf("Oracle Database connection failed  %s", dberr)
    } else {
        log.Printf("Oracle Database connection established using existing password!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Got a sqlnet.ora with a path to a wallet file that needs fixing?

Comment: @ChristopherJones Hi, I am trying to connect to remote database. As you mentioned sqlnet.ora file, is it something we need to put or configure in our local?

Comment: It will be best for you to ask your DBA, or someone else who has connected, what setup they use.

Comment: Edit sqlnet.ora.   WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = file) (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY="$TNS_ADMIN")))